# I have a huge space between two lines of code how do i remove?

Tags: html

Between:

```
<h2>Menu</h2>
```

and

```
<h5>Hover to see more!</h5>
```

I have this huge gap, is there a way to remove it?

For more references this is my code before heading 2:

```
     <div class="container">
        <img src="Lato Font Test.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="text"><p>About Us // Origin</p><p>Sample Text</p><p>Sample Text</p><p>Sample Text</p></div>
            </div>
            </div>

    <br></br>
```

And after heading 5:

```
 <ul id="accordion">
           <li>
               <h2>MENU // SOUPS</h2>
               <div class="content">
                   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                   tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p>
               </div>
           </li>
```

Picture Reference: [http://i.imgur.com/Imc3DPb.png](https://i.imgur.com/Imc3DPb.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try playing with `margin` and `padding` of those h2 and h5 elements

Comment: Header elements have a default `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` that you have to override in CSS if you don't want them.

Comment: please post your complete code..

Answer (score 0):

One of your elements has a default padding or margin.  You can inspect your elements with your browsers dev tools to figure out which if not both is causing the issue.  Adjust your paddings and margins using `padding: x;` and `margin: x;` x being the amount of pixels [ex. 5px] you want.